# Optional Generic Parameter or a way of combating type errasure

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-erasure

The question boils down to "is it possible to have  <T,U, optional V> ?" or a design pattern that would resolve my issue below.

The hierarchy of the thing I'm working on could be summarized like this:

```
Dispatcher
 - Controller
   - Main View Component
   - Optional Mini Controller
     - Optional View Component
```

Each and every component here has an abstract that does a lot of the back end, and every concrete class just fills in some gaps.

### The thing that bothers me is this:

#### Definition:

```
Controller<T extends AbstractWhatever, U> {
    T abstractMainView;
    AbstractMiniController abstractMiniController;
}
```

#### In action:

```
Controller<ConcreteMainView, UnderlyingObjectType> {
    abstractMainView.ConcreteMethod; // works
    abstractMiniController.ConcreteMethod; // does not work
}
```

Because the main controller has a Generic `T` for the main view, the main view is declared as said `T` and when I make my concrete main controller, I give it a concrete class for `T`, it now knows all the methods of my main view.

But because the optional controller / view don't have a concrete class given as a type parameter, I have to do a bunch of casts:

```
Controller<MainView, Type> {
    MainView.doStuff();
    ((ConcreteOptionalController) COP).doStuff();
    ((ConcreteOptionalController) COP).doSomeMoreStuff();
    ((ConcreteOptionalController) COP).doAllTheStuffs();
}
```

Thing is, I can't give the controller a type parameter:

```
Controller<MainView, Type, OptionalController>
```

Because at times I don't have anything to put there. Am I just stuck with the unending kilometer long casts + statements, or is there a way of making this work more nicely?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The field `abstractMiniController` must have a type that is statically known (even when you use a type parameter, the static type would be one mentioned in `extends`). You can only call methods available for this static type.

Comment: `AbstractMiniController abstractMiniController` it does have a type, an abstract. But I will inevitably initialize it with a concrete type if I ever use it. However due to type errasure, I have to cast it to use any methods defined in my concrete class. This is not true for the `MainView` since it was defined as a type parameter, thus it's type is known locally. I can't give the `mini` a type parameter since I can't guarantee it will be used, thus I use an abstract class as a definition and always null check within the abstract main controller.

Comment: It is the static type that determines which methods can be called without a type cast. The concrete object passed in is totally irrelevant for type checking.

Comment: Hence my question. If I could have an optional type parameter, I could have it be of that type `<V extends AbstractMiniController>`. Is this possible `yes/no`, is there some design pattern that would make the mini controller be of a concrete type `yes/no` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as an optional type parameter, and no, you can't make the mini controller statically a concrete type (unless you declare is as the concrete type).